# Geofencing and offline maps in Android

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid, geofencing

It's amazing how easy it is possible to use geofencing with Google Maps API. However for that you have to be "connected" and use online maps. However I can not find how to use geofencing functionality for offline maps and what, if any, offline map provider supports it on Android. Would be thankful for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up with some hybrid solution. I used MapBox and Open Street Maps for offline map functionality together with Google Play services that allowed me to add geofencing functionality. Somehow I was thinking that geofencing requires to use Google Maps and that was obviously not correct.

Comment: Open Street map can be used to offline map functionality. Can we simply use Open street map to add geofencing?